# Different table type in C# ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a table to my web form. When I try to set the properties of the table's cell to display in solution explorer, I don't see the `Valign Property` mentioned in my book exercise. I see properties that start with "aria". Am I using the wrong type of table?

Someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valign is not valid HTML5, it's been deprecated. Use CSS instead and use the

```
vertical-align:alignment (top, bottom, middle)
```

instead.

The HTML way:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:middle;">Vertically centered text</td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;">Vertically top aligned text</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The ASP.NET WebForms way:

```
<asp:Table id="myTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle">
            Vertically centered text
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Top">
            Vertically top aligned text
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: I dont understand why the table I created on this empty web form is different then the table that was an example in the excerise. The table that was the solution to my project had the "correct" table with the valign property in the solution explorer, But the one automatically created when I insert from the table use aira properties. It's like they are two different types of tables.

Comment: Are you using a <asp:Table> tag in the Project and a normal HTML <table> in the book excercise?

Comment: Im using the <table> </table> tags.

Comment: Ok, see the edited response. The valign attribute is the old way of doing things (pre HTML5), that's probably why you aren't seeing that attribute in whatever editor you're using.

Comment: The old way was <td valign="middle"> but the new (HTML 5) way is <td style="vertical-align:middle;">, they do the same thing, but the latter one conforms to present day standards.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why the properties of this table is different then the properties in my new table.

Comment: Ok, so you have TWO tables in a solution and on one you can actually see the valign attribute and set it and on the other you don't?

Comment: Okay thank you Jaggen. I think It's working now. Yea I'm using an older programming book, it's short of throwing me off. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of assistance. :)